# How does the poly1305-donna algorithm work

Tags: c, algorithm, authentication, encryption

Ive been looking at implementing a poly1305 algorithm in C and I came across this github project [here](https://github.com/floodyberry/poly1305-donna/blob/master/poly1305-donna-32.h)

One thing Ive never really done (but I need to do to implement this algorithm) is doing math operations on large numbers. The link above Implements this large number math but I can't seem to figure out how it works.

The first step is to clamp r (clear specific bits) but I don't know why r, a 16 byte value, is stored in 32 bit number array of length 5, nor how the clamping is accomplished in this code. (U8TO32 is just a little endian load function)

```
/* r &= 0xffffffc0ffffffc0ffffffc0fffffff */
st->r[0] = (U8TO32(&key[ 0])     ) & 0x3ffffff;
st->r[1] = (U8TO32(&key[ 3]) >> 2) & 0x3ffff03;
st->r[2] = (U8TO32(&key[ 6]) >> 4) & 0x3ffc0ff;
st->r[3] = (U8TO32(&key[ 9]) >> 6) & 0x3f03fff;
st->r[4] = (U8TO32(&key[12]) >> 8) & 0x00fffff;
```

The multiplication, addition and mod steps are done here. h is just an accumulator, and will initially start as all zeros. and...well I just get completely lost after that.

```
s1 = r1 * 5;
s2 = r2 * 5;
s3 = r3 * 5;
s4 = r4 * 5;

/* h += m[i] */
    h0 += (U8TO32(m+ 0)     ) & 0x3ffffff;
    h1 += (U8TO32(m+ 3) >> 2) & 0x3ffffff;
    h2 += (U8TO32(m+ 6) >> 4) & 0x3ffffff;
    h3 += (U8TO32(m+ 9) >> 6) & 0x3ffffff;
    h4 += (U8TO32(m+12) >> 8) | hibit;

    /* h *= r */
    d0 = ((unsigned long long)h0 * r0) + ((unsigned long long)h1 * s4) + ((unsigned long long)h2 * s3) + ((unsigned long long)h3 * s2) + ((unsigned long long)h4 * s1);
    d1 = ((unsigned long long)h0 * r1) + ((unsigned long long)h1 * r0) + ((unsigned long long)h2 * s4) + ((unsigned long long)h3 * s3) + ((unsigned long long)h4 * s2);
    d2 = ((unsigned long long)h0 * r2) + ((unsigned long long)h1 * r1) + ((unsigned long long)h2 * r0) + ((unsigned long long)h3 * s4) + ((unsigned long long)h4 * s3);
    d3 = ((unsigned long long)h0 * r3) + ((unsigned long long)h1 * r2) + ((unsigned long long)h2 * r1) + ((unsigned long long)h3 * r0) + ((unsigned long long)h4 * s4);
    d4 = ((unsigned long long)h0 * r4) + ((unsigned long long)h1 * r3) + ((unsigned long long)h2 * r2) + ((unsigned long long)h3 * r1) + ((unsigned long long)h4 * r0);

    /* (partial) h %= p */
                  c = (unsigned long)(d0 >> 26); h0 = (unsigned long)d0 & 0x3ffffff;
    d1 += c;      c = (unsigned long)(d1 >> 26); h1 = (unsigned long)d1 & 0x3ffffff;
    d2 += c;      c = (unsigned long)(d2 >> 26); h2 = (unsigned long)d2 & 0x3ffffff;
    d3 += c;      c = (unsigned long)(d3 >> 26); h3 = (unsigned long)d3 & 0x3ffffff;
    d4 += c;      c = (unsigned long)(d4 >> 26); h4 = (unsigned long)d4 & 0x3ffffff;
    h0 += c * 5;  c =                (h0 >> 26); h0 =                h0 & 0x3ffffff;
    h1 += c;
```

Comment: You might be better off asking in the crypto StackExchange network.

Comment: After a quick look, it appears that only 26 bits of r are stored in each 32 bit value. The top 6 bits are masked off. Similarly, the top 6 bits are masked off of the 32-bit values when the 128-bit message chunk is added to h. As to why it seems to use 26-bit chunks for everything (particularly when the intermediate values, d, are at 64-bit precision), I don't know. Compare, for example, OpenSSL's implementation: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/poly1305/poly1305.c